# The image gets blurred after zoom or scale action in GIMP. How to get clear image?

Tags: gimp, resize, image-quality, image-editing

Since I am a beginner, I don’t have much knowledge of designing tools. I am trying to resize the image using GIMP but it gets blurred. Please tell me how to get clear image after resize?

Answer (score 2):

As image is an **Rasterized** based element, every image formed up with no.of pixels together. So when you enlarge a small image, automatically the pixel will expand and shows like blurred. That's reason where "Resultion" point comes, more resolution = more pixel in an inch = clarity stays long while expand.

That's why **Vector** objects won't show blurness....due to it's formed with line based drawings.

So your image will blur, if you scale it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot enlarge an image without blurring.  A big sharp image contains a lot more data than a small image of similar sharpness. When you enlarge the image, you are not adding any detail/data in it. `Big image, little data => blur`.

Answer (score 0):

This is going unnoticed but I have a feeling that the SCALE DOWN command is blurring a lot more than it should. This wasn't the default behaviour of GIMP in older versions. So there is definitely a problem with this software. We all know that scaling an image renders its properties lost but this isn't the case here. There is something wrong with GIMP 2.10 series.